# Airflow SparkSubmitOperator with Yarn Cluster Mode not being able to track application status

Tags: airflow

I started reading about how we could run Spark batch jobs using Airflow.
I have tried using SparkSubmitOperator in local and it works fine. However, I need a recommendation, if we could use it in cluster mode. 
The only problem I see when using in cluster mode is that, here the application status not being able to be tracked,ref shared in the link below:
https://albertusk95.github.io/posts/2019/12/airflow-tracks-spark-driver-status-cluster-deployment/

Please suggest if anyone  has tried using this operator and works well in cluster mode, or if there is any issue using it.